# Should we make [definition] a synonym for [terminology]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The meaning of both tags seems very close. So far there are two questions that use these tags, and they both use both tags.

I suggest [definition](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) be a synonym for [terminology](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) since the latter is very slightly broader and could cover how a term is used, not just its official definition.

(Alternatively, I suggest [definition](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) be deleted, for the same reason. Its two questions are already covered by the [terminology](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tag.)

Comment: As a note, in my response (which I've since removed), I mentioned that the differences between the two may too subtle to keep them apart and so I would merge them if there's some reasonable consensus amongst us to do that.

Comment: Matt untagged his two questions with definition, so it should disappear when the background scripts come through.

Comment: Based on the 3 tagged questions, I provided a tag wiki definition for the terminology tag.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see what value [definition](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) adds, either as a tag or a synonym.  I would just kill it and use [terminology](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology).

(I'm not completely convinced that [terminology](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) is valuable either, but I *am* convinced that we don't need two of these.)

Comment: I'm not sure about [terminology] either. It seems a bit like a meta tag, which I've been reading guidelines on (short version: they're not good) recently on another StackExchange.

Comment: I like Monica's suggestion I must admit, but the advantage of making the definition tag a synonym is that it prevents it from coming back over and over... Mind you we can remove it from the two questions and see if it does come back.

Comment: The site is small and young; we can watch to see if it comes back and then, if necessary, create the synonym.  Since the existence of the synonym is what caused issues in the first place here, I'm proposing that we eliminate the tag and thus those issues, and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** ; they are so near the same that they should be synonymized and [terminology](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) should be the main tag name.

Comment: What are you going to do if I down vote both your options? What if everyone does that? This model isn't suited to polling. :)

Answer (score -1):

**No** ; these tags are different and should be kept alive as they are.